# ktor cannot access class in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

I am following the getting started guide for a ktor server. It actually runs but I am seeing errors in IntelliJ like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I can start it on the console and via the run button in intelliJ though. Even invalidate caches & restart did not help.

I am adding these dependencies:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktor_version")
```

Comment: What version of Ktor and IntelliJ IDEA do you use?

Comment: It could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19504. Please try with 1.5.10 Kotlin IDE plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19504#focus=Comments-27-5150305.0-0

Comment: @AlekseiTirman 2021.2.1 (Community Edition)

Comment: Please wait for Kotlin 1.5.31 IDE plugin to get this problem fixed.